# Magento 2 : To find out whether Single Store Mode value changed or not

Tags: magento2, configuration, system-config

Is there any class/file from `module-config` module that can be useful whether **single_store_mode** value has been changed from yes to no or vice-versa.

Have checked **admin_config** related events but these are not useful as these are calling after save.

**EDIT:**

I want to have before Save as well as after Save value so i can compare whether value has been changed or not?

Tried to implement two approaches but unfortunately it's not working.

1. By applying `source_model` on the `general/single_store_mode/enabled` in custom module's `system.xml`
2. Using beforeSave() plugin on `Magento\Config\Model\Config`

Answer (score 2):

Inject `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface` and use `$this->scopeConfig->getValue('general/single_store_mode/enabled');` to read the value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use then @Philipp Sander solution in a more elegant way

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;


class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper

{

    protected $_scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }


    /**
    * Use scope magento config
    *
    * @param string $config_path
    */

    public function getStoreConfig($config_path)
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            $config_path,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

Then you inject that helper in your constructor

```
protected $_helper;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $helper 
) {
    ...
    $this->_helper = $helper;
}

 public function execute() {
    $singleStoreMode = $this->_helper->getStoreConfig('general/single_store_mode/enabled');
}
```

**Note : Don't forget to generate the new DI classes :**

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: this is exactly what I said. How is it more elegant to wrap it in a helper?

Comment: @Philipp Sander it's more elegant to use `getStoreConfig()` function and use it in other files if needed, it also good what you did, that's why I gave you +1

Comment: when extending a class, you should make sure that the parent constructor is being called. and if you take a look at abstracthelper you will see that it already has a scopeconfig. so no need to inject it again. what excatly is you benefit of having that helper? why not inject scopeconfig into your service directly?